# If-else doesn't work as expected in Appium 2.0 with TestNG

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

I'm trying to run a if - else loop for two conditions. the code checks the if condition and tries to find that but if it fails it doesn't execute the else code.

```
if (driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("___")).isDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"OK\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"menu_edit\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Locations")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("0")).click();
    deleteLocation();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("cancel_dm")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("userProfile")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"Delete Account\"]")).click();
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"YES\"]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"OK\"]")).click();
}
else {
    driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"OK\"]")).click();
}
```

Here the code never executes the else block and gets stuck at the if condition even when it is unable to locate that element

Comment: run a debugger, and evaluate the if-condition

Comment: I tried but it never exits the if condition and tries to find that element

Comment: what do you mean "exits the if condition"?

Comment: When i run a debugger it  tries to find that element and it returns element not found error at the end.

Here is the console output for the same:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Command: [59123c74-3fb3-47f5-9c27-46996651281f, findElement {using=xpath, value=//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="____"]}]

Comment: so, an Exception is thrown? And you expected your else block to catch that Exception? I would recommend you to study the basics of Java before trying to utilize more complex tools.

Comment: That is an element not found exception which is thrown, it is trying to find the element which i've put in the if condition.
Since it's unable to find the element it should go to the else block, right ?
Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: no, it should not since AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN. A thrown Exception is not the same as a failed condition.

Comment: @SandeshRathod - You might want to refactor your code to use `driver.findElements()` which will return a list of `WebElement` and then you can check if the list is empty and have your `else` section handle it. If elements were found, then you can iterate the elements list and then do whatever operations you need.